# How to build libcurl-gnutls.so from source code

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, gnutls

Where can I find the source code and instructions for building libcurl-gnutls.so?

I'm working on a project that needs libcurl-gnutls.so. I am required to build it from source code - I am not allowed to simply install it with "apt-get install libcurl". Unfortunately, my google-fu is failing me and I can't find a source code repository or instructions to build libcurl-gnutls.so anywhere.

Here's what I have found:

Linux-from-scratch has well-documented instructions for building libcurl.so, here: https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/curl.html. That lets me build libcurl.so with gnutls, but not libcurl-gnutls.so.

The curl website (curl.se), has detailed instructions on its various options here: https://curl.se/docs/install.html. Those show me how to build libcurl with gnutls, but the end product is still libcurl.so, not libcurl-gnutls.so.

When I run ldd -r on my project, it identifies the functions it needs (curl_easy_init, curl_easy_setopt, curl_easy_perform, and curl_easy_cleanup). I can find those symbols in both libcurl.so and a pre-built libcurl-gnutls.so. This leads me to suspect that libcurl-gnutls.so **is** libcurl.so, published under a different name. However, renaming libcurl.so to libcurl-gnutls.so is not sufficient to meet the dependency requirements. I could try altering the libcurl project to set its name and version to libcurl-gnutls (not that I know how to do it - I would poke around until I figure it out), but I don't know how appropriate that would be.

I found one other question on Stack Overflow about libcurl-gnutls ([How to create lib curl-gnutls.so.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012612/how-to-create-lib-curl-gnutls-so-4/37013062)), but the answers to that are to install a pre-built version via apt-get install, which I am not allowed to do.

Comment: 20.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/curl → → http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.68.0.orig.tar.gz . .... There  is a patch `debian/patches/90_gnutls.patch` in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.6.debian.tar.xz ..... `configure --with-gnutls --without-ssl`

Comment: Thanks, @KnudLarsen, but the patch file appears to fall short.  It still builds as libcurl.so.4, and still has SONAME set to libcurl.so.4 internally.

Comment: I got **lib/** `{libcurl.a,libcurl-gnutls.a,libcurl-gnutls.la,libcurl-gnutls.so,libcurl-gnutls.so.4,libcurl-gnutls.so.4.6.0,libcurl.la,libcurl.so,libcurl.so.4,libcurl.so.4.6.0,pkgconfig/}` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete answer cobbled together from everyone's input (Thanks especially to Knud Larsen and Wassim Dhif):

`libcurl-gnutls.so` **is** just `libcurl.so` built with gnutls support.  Archives for the project are here: https://curl.se/download

1. Change the SONAME that `libcurl.so` is built with by editing `ltmain.sh` to change:

   ```
    if test -n "$soname_spec";
    then eval soname=\"$soname_spec\"
   ```

To:

```
    if test -n "$soname_spec"; then
    soname=libcurl-gnutls.so.4
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do it, but this works and I need to move on.

Alternatively, you can modify the the `SONAME` after `libcurl.so` is built with:

```
    patchelf –set-soname libcurl-gnutls.so.4 libcurl.so
```

2. Check your client (the program or shared library that requires `libcurl-gnutls.so` as a dependency), to see if it requires version information.
   For instance, when I run `objdump -p myprogram`, I get this:

   ```
    Version References:
    required from libcurl-gnutls.so.4:
    0x0b103d23 0x00 14 CURL_GNUTLS_3
   ```

To build `libcurl-gnutls.so` with this version information:

2a. Set the version information to version 3:
In lib/libcurl.vers.in change:

```
CURL_@CURL_LT_SHLIB_VERSIONED_FLAVOUR@4
```

To:

```
CURL_@CURL_LT_SHLIB_VERSIONED_FLAVOUR@3
```

2b. Use `--enable-versioned-symbols` when configuring the libcurl project. This adds  the required version information.

```
./configure --with-gnutls --enable-versioned-symbols [other arguments as needed]
```

The final product may be named `libcurl.so`, but can be renamed.  It will have its `SONAME` set to `libcurl-gnutls.so.4` and will have the required version information.

Answer (score 0):

`libcurl-gnutls.so` actually just comes from a cURL built with `gnutls` support. You can find the repository here: https://github.com/curl/curl

Check out the `docs/INSTALL.md`. It has all the information you need to build cURL, specifically the part about `Building from git`.

Here is a snippet you might need:

```
./configure --with-openssl [--with-gnutls --with-wolfssl]
make
make test (optional)
make install
```